# Angular formgroup not updated with checkbox value

Tags: angular

I'm having a hard time figuring out something that is very likely a mistake on my part.

I'm creating a custom dynamic form component that will allow developers to create forms using only TS. The problem is happening with checkboxes. After If I read FormGroup's value before clicking the checkbox it's `undefined`, if I click on it, it becomes (correctly) `true`, but if I click again, it remains (uncorrectly) `true`. What am I missing here?

I've created a stackblitz to show this behavior. Please look at the console for output.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fydiwl

Thanks!

Comment: follow the steps in this article. this is the correct way to build custom form items. https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/. in short you implement `ControlValueAccessor` and then can that component as you would a native input element.

Comment: @delashum thanks, I was able to fix the code using yurzui's answer. But I'll definitely take a look at the article later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that Angular can't recognize the appropriate ControlValueAccessor for your control since your're using dynamic `type`:

```
<input ... type="{{inputType}}"
```

while accessor for checkbox [looks for specific type](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f57e77eeb46907359046caff03376aa4a8d8ae7f/packages/forms/src/directives/checkbox_value_accessor.ts#L44)

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=checkbox]...
```

This means that you have to specify `<input type="checkbox"` explicitly in order it to be working.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqyzrn?file=src/app/checkbox/checkbox.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Guess I should've checked the source code first :D. thanks for your help :)

Comment: I think that it's not such transparently so it is not your fault